# Rails hash to will_paginate format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

I have a hash that contains an array of hashes (tickets) and meta data received via an API call. The endpoint uses will_paginate gem and returns the results.

Is there a way to transform this hash into a format which can be used as a parameter for `will_paginate` in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`will_paginate` can make use of plain arrays instead of ActiveRecord scopes.

You just need to treat your data before. There is plenty of resource on how to do it:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/13521-will_paginate-can-paginate-plain-ruby-arrays
https://gist.github.com/denmarkin/817327